# checked data binding is not working for radio buttons in knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
<div id="distance-filter" data-bind="foreach: model.distance">
<p ><input type="radio" value="value" name="distance" data-bind="checked: model.check"> <span data-bind="text:model.check"></span></p>
</div>
```

the checked data binding is not working 
my model is as follows

```
var model= {    
    filter_list: ko.observableArray([{filter:'restaurant'},{filter:'hospital'},{filter:'atm'},{filter:'cafe'}]),
    fav_list: ko.observableArray([{fav:'Pizzahut'},{fav:'Dominos'},{fav:'Barista'}]),
     distance: ko.observableArray([{value: 500},{value: 1000},{value: 5000},{value: 10000}]),
     check: ko.observable(1000)

};
```

Comment: What is your `ko.applybindings(....)` statement? You probably don't need `model.` in your binding.

Comment: ` ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());`
i have used it to bind the view Model
Everythings working except for the radiobutton's checked binding

Comment: It is not working because your distance observableArray doesn't contain "check" property and you are in foreach loop,  so what you could do is :
<p ><input type="radio" value="value" name="distance" data-bind="checked: $parent.model.check"> <span data-bind="text:model.check"></span></p>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not setting the correct value of each item. Rather they all have the value `"value"`.

Take out

```
value="value"
```

and change your data-bind to

```
data-bind="checked: model.check, checkedValue: value"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you ultimately want to do, but it at least gets the check doing something interesting.

Although you can refer to `model` because it is a global variable, you should not. (It should not be a global variable.) Instead of `model.distance`, just use `distance` in your `foreach` binding. Within the foreach, the context changes. To refer to `checked` (which isn't defined within each `distance` object), you need to use `$parent.checked`. You can use `value` directly, because the context is the current `distance` object.

What you probably want to do is have each button labeled with its own `value`, and then print the value of `checked` outside the foreach to indicate what its current value is. As written, the value of `checked` is printed beside each button, and they all change when you change which button is selected.

Also: the value of `checked` should be a string, as values of `input` items are string.

```js
var model = {
  distance: ko.observableArray([{
    value: 500
  }, {
    value: 1000
  }, {
    value: 5000
  }, {
    value: 10000
  }]),
  check: ko.observable('1000')
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="distance-filter" data-bind="foreach: distance">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="distance" data-bind="attr: { value: value }, checked: $parent.check">
    <span data-bind="text:$parent.check"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```